# How to display an image larger than the screen using a scrollPane JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, scrollpane

How would one use a scrollPane to display an image larger than the screen in an application that is full screen? I have an image that is about 8000x3800 pixels and I would like to be able to move and interact with the entire image without having to resize it. If you wish specifics about my code or in general just ask.

```
public class SourceCodeVersion8 extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane mapAnchorO = addMapAnchor();
        Scene mapScene = new Scene(mapAnchorO);
        primaryStage.setScene(mapScene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //Creates an AnchorPane for the map
    private AnchorPane addMapAnchor()
    {
        AnchorPane mapAnchor = new AnchorPane();
        ScrollPane mapScrollO = addMapScroll();
        mapAnchor.getChildren().add(mapScrollO);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
        return mapAnchor;
    }

    //Creates an ImageView for the map
    private ImageView addMapView()
    {
        Image mapImage = new Image("WorldProvincialMap-v1.01.png");
        ImageView mapView = new ImageView(mapImage);
        return mapView;
    }

    //Creates a scrollPane for the map
    private ScrollPane addMapScroll()
    {
        ScrollPane mapScroll = new ScrollPane();
        ImageView mapViewO = addMapView();
        mapScroll.setContent(mapViewO);
        mapScroll.setPannable(true);
        return mapScroll;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have but it does not allow panning even though I enabled that option. In addition it doesn't show the scroll bars even if I enable that option.

Comment: Edited question to include my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only set 2 of 4 anchors for the `ScrollPane`, which is why the `ScrollPane` is never resized and just resizes to a size that allows displaying the whole image.

Therefore no scrollbars are neccessary and panning cannot be done.

You could fix this by also setting the right and bottom anchors. Alternatively use the `ScrollPane` as root of the `Scene` directly.

```
private AnchorPane addMapAnchor() {
    AnchorPane mapAnchor = new AnchorPane();
    ScrollPane mapScrollO = addMapScroll();
    mapAnchor.getChildren().add(mapScrollO);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(mapScrollO, 0.0);
    return mapAnchor;
}
```